How to add IAM permission to Cloudfront in to be inherited by Lambda@Edge?
I am using CDK to create a Cloudfront distribution and a Lambda@Edge function to control access to it.
The problem is, the function needs permission to read a secret from the Secret Manager.  It is my understanding that the function inherits the service-role of its distribution, which makes sense to me. [EDIT: I now believe that this statement might not be true.  See response.]
What I don’t understand though is how to get the service-role from the distribution in order to grant it.  The obviously right way to do is:
Secret.grantRead(distribution.grantPrincipal)

Obviously right, except that the type CloudFrontWebDistribution does not have a grantPrincipal.

I am not sure below statement is correct. Do you have any reference to prove this statement?

It is my understanding that the function inherits the service-role of its distribution, which makes sense to me.

Now, talking about the solution, you just need to do the following:

Create an IAM Role
Provide that IAM Role permissions to access secrets from the Secrets Manager
Attach the IAM Role to the Lambda function

Here is the CDK code snippet in C#, that I wrote to run Angular app with SSR on Lambda@Edge. You just need to change the IAM permissions as per your need.
// 1.1 Create Lambda execution role
Role lambdaExecutionRole = new Role(this, "lambda-execution-role", new RoleProps
{
    AssumedBy = new ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com")
});

lambdaExecutionRole.AddManagedPolicy(ManagedPolicy.FromAwsManagedPolicyName("service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"));

// 1.2. Do not log into CloudWatch as logs might be costly
var policy = new Policy(this, "cw-deny-policy", new PolicyProps
{
    Statements = new[] {
        new PolicyStatement(new PolicyStatementProps {
            Effect = Effect.DENY,
            Actions = new [] { "logs:CreateLogGroup", "logs:CreateLogStream", "logs:PutLogEvents" },
            Resources = new [] { "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*" }
        })
    }
});

lambdaExecutionRole.AttachInlinePolicy(policy);

// 2. Edge Function
var lambdaAtEdgeSSRFunction = new EdgeFunction(this, "ssr-lambda", new EdgeFunctionProps
{
    MemorySize = 1024,
    Timeout = Duration.Seconds(30),
    Runtime = Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
    Handler = "lambda.handler",
    Code = Code.FromAsset("./src/UtilityAppsCdk/DefaultArtifacts/SSREdgeLambda.zip"),
    Role = lambdaExecutionRole
});


“I am not sure below statement is correct. Do you have any reference to prove this statement?”  Granting the Function permission as described here did not work, so I ... asked ChatGPT.  I will try again.

The code that I used (posted above) worked for me, and should work for you as well. Just add permissions to access secrets manager.

There is no need to write any of this code - just use grantRead.

There are multiple ways of doing the same thing. Creating a role allows you to better control what permissions a Lambda function can have.

Yes, for sure. I'm just saying there's no reason to write all this code here - you don't gain anything in this case.

A CloudFront distribution does not have a role - that's why the construct doesn't have a grantPrincipal property. The lambda's role is its own thing.
To grant the function access to the secret, you simply use grantRead:
mySecret.grantRead(myFunction);

You don't have to create the role or attach any policies to it manually.

That is what I tried first.  When it did not work, I tried fancier stuff.  I will try basics again, maybe I had a different problem.

In what way didn't it work? Can you post your code?

— sorry, I deleted it, but I got the usual “no identity-based policy allows the request” error.

Then something else must be wrong with your setup - grantRead definitely works.
